# Set urxvt to work with 256 colors

Tags: colors, xterm, urxvt, rxvt

I had spent so much time to try to get `urxvt` to work with 256 colors. I am using Ubuntu. I have followed a part of [this post](http://scie.nti.st/2008/10/13/get-rxvt-unicode-with-256-color-support-on-ubunut/)

```
cd ~
infocmp -L rxvt-unicode > rxvt-unicode.terminfo

vi rxvt-unicode.terminfo
# Change the following from:
#
#    lines_of_memory#0, max_colors#88, max_pairs#256,
#
# to:
#
#    lines_of_memory#0, max_colors#256, max_pairs#32767

# Make .terminfo dir if you don't already have it
install -d .terminfo

# Rebuild terminfo for rxvt-unicode
tic -o .terminfo/ rxvt-unicode.terminfo

# Cleanup
rm rxvt-unicode.terminfo
```

`tput colors` gives 256 now instead of 88 earlier
But when I run the `256colors2.pl` script, the output is not as expected.
[image: Here is the screenshot]

`echo $TERM` gives `rxvt-unicode` as output in urxvt.

`echo $COLORTERM` gives `rxvt-xpm` as output in vim.

`echo &t_Co` gives 256 as output in vim.

Please help me figure out how to set up 256 colors for urxvt. My main aim is to use vim(in terminal) with the gruvbox theme.

Response for an answer:

I have already set the `t_Co=256` option in vim. I don't use tmux. Using it doesn't change the result of the `256colors2.pl` script. The TERM in tmux is already set to `screen-256color`. I tried copying the `/usr/share/terminfo/r/rxvt-256color` to `~/.terminfo/r/rxvt-256color`. No change on TERM or the results of the tests. Finally I used [the colortest CJD14 has linked](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1349), many colors are not working. Only a bunch of colors are being coloured. So something is definitely broken or configured wrong.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, finally found my mistake. It seems like you need to install the package `rxvt-unicode-256color` to get 256 color support.

```
sudo apt-get install rxvt-unicode-256color
```

is the answer to my problems.

Comment: In Debian `rxvt-unicode-256color` is a virtual package for `rxvt-unicode` which supports 256 colors. In spite of this being installed, I'm unable to get 256 color support in neovim even though urxvt has 256 color support.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying /usr/share/terminfo/r/rxvt-256color to ~/.terminfo/r/rxvt-256color

And in your vimrc add

```
set t_Co=256
```

Also add

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

In your tmux, screen conf if used.

Oh and check out CSApprox vim plugin when you get the full color support it makes many themes look great in terminals.

Also try this script in vim to verify full color support. 
[colortest](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1349)

Comment: Adding `TERM=screen-256color` to your `.tmux.conf` is a terrible idea. The correct way to do it is `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`

Comment: I have already set the `t_Co` option. I don't use tmux. Using it doesn't change the result of the `256colors2.pl` script. The TERM in tmux is already set to `screen-256color`. I tried copying the `/usr/share/terminfo/r/rxvt-256color` to `~/.terminfo/r/rxvt-256color`. No change on TERM or the results of the tests. Finally I used the colortest you have linked, many colors are not working. Only a bunch of colors are being coloured.